# const keyword usage in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was reading the source for a MeteorJS package ([this one](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/blob/devel/packages/react-meteor-data/createContainer.jsx)) when I came across this:

```
const {
  getMeteorData,
  pure = true,
} = expandedOptions;
```

I did some research to figure out what this code would do, but couldn't find any other instance of *const* being used like this, or any documentation to clarify it for me.

Any hints, please?

Comment: It's more [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) than `const`.

Comment: Thanks for the reference :}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using es6 to unpack (or destructure) the values inside the expandedOptions object.

```
const val = {a:1, b:"hello"};
const {
    a,
    b
} = val;

console.log(a); //1
console.log(b); //"hello"
```

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't have found it by myself (I'lll accept the answer as soon as the SO let me do it)